# Will Queue Trigger Auto retry after meet function timeout

Tags: function, timeout, azure-functions, queuetrigger

My situation is.

Function timeout is set 1 hour

Function 1 start and takes 2 hours to complete

Function 2 start after 30 mins from Function 1

When function 1 reach the timeout, it also interrupts the function 2.

I want to know if the function reach the timeout, will it be retried ? 
Will it interrupt others running ?

Comment: If a function times out, depending on the trigger type it will not be retried, it also will not interrupt other functions. But from your description, it sounds like if you have a function that is taking 2 hours, functions are probably not the correct solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

When a function times out, an exception is thrown; however, it shouldn't interrupt other functions currently running. A queue-triggered function will be retried, based on the value of the [`maxDequeueCount` setting in your `host.json` file.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#hostjson-settings)